# How does simulation help check if model assumptions are met?

Tags: regression

I am trying to understand how simulation can be used to check if (regression) model assumptions are met.

For example here is a linear regression model:
$$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x + \epsilon$$

I understand that the errors and the response have the following distributions:

$$\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$$

$$f(\epsilon) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{\epsilon^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

$$y|x \sim N(\beta_0 + \beta_1x, \sigma^2)$$

$$f(y|x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{(y-\beta_0 - \beta_1x)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

Once the model has been fit on some data, we get the following distributions:

$$\hat{y} = \hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1x$$

$$\hat{\epsilon} = y - \hat{y}$$
$$\hat{\epsilon} \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$$

$$\hat{y}|x \sim N(\hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1x, \hat{\sigma}^2 \left( \frac{1}{n} + \frac{(x - \bar{x})^2}{\sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2} \right))$$

$$\hat{\beta}_1 \sim N\left(\hat{\beta}_1, \frac{\hat{\sigma}^2}{\sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2}\right)$$

$$\hat{\beta}_0 \sim N\left(\hat{\beta}_0, \hat{\sigma}^2 \left( \frac{1}{n} + \frac{\bar{x}^2}{\sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2} \right)\right)$$

From here, using the properties of the Normal Distribution (i.e. adding normal distributions together produces a normal distribution and subtracting normal distributions from each other also produces a normal distribution ), I can see that $\hat{\epsilon}$ can ONLY be Normally Distributed if the distribution of the observed $y$ conditional on $x$ (i.e. $y|x$), $\hat{\beta}_0$ and $\hat{\beta}_1$ are ALL Normally Distributed. If even one of them are not normally distributed, then (in theory) $\hat{\epsilon}$  will not be normally distributed. (I can also see that if $\hat{\sigma}$ is non-constant i.e. heteroskedastic, then the distributions of $\hat{\beta}_0$ and $\hat{\beta}_1$ might not be normal).

So here is my question: **How can simulating new data points be used to help check if the model assumptions are being met?**

I can understand the logic behind a cross validation style approach: Fit the model on 70% of the data, and see if the predicted errors (i.e. residuals) from the other 30% of the data is  Normally Distributed (i.e. using QQ plots or Kolmogorov-Smirnov).

**But how can you simulate completely new pairs of data points ($x_i, y_i$) and use them to test if the model assumptions are being met? And how will this help?**

- Step 1: For example, I can choose some value of $x_i$ and simulate multiple values of $y_i$ for this $x_i$ . Each $y_i$ will be a random realization from a $N(\hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1x, \hat{\sigma}^2 \left( \frac{1}{n} + \frac{(x - \bar{x})^2}{\sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2} \right))$.
- Step 2: I can then make my model predict the value of each $\hat{y_i}$.
- Step 3: Then, I can check the distribution of all $\hat{y_i}$ to see if they are Normally Distributed
- I can repeat Step 1 - Step 3 for new values of $x_i$ and use a QQ plot to check if all these error/residuals are (collectively) normally distributed.

**The way I see it, in this simulation, all $\hat{\epsilon_i} = y_i - \hat{y_i}$ will only be Normally Distributed if my regression model always produces normally distributed $\hat{y_i}$. And my regression model can only produce normally distributed $\hat{y_i}$ if the data used to create the regression model was conditionally normal.**

Is this the correct understanding? Or is this a circular argument and the errors from the simulated points will necessarily be normally distributed even if the model assumptions are not met ?

Comment: You state that $$\hat{\epsilon} \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$$ But, if the $y$ are normal distributed, then indeed $\hat{\epsilon}$ follows a normal distribution as well. However, it is a slightly more complex expression. (and also, the true relationship between $y$ and $x$ needs to be in the space of the models, or otherwise there will be a bias as well). The distribution of the residuals is not the same as the distribution of the error terms.

Comment: Also the expressions for $\hat{y}|x$, $\hat{\beta}_1$ and $\hat{\beta}_2$ are not so clear.

Comment: As example of a the residuals you can consider the simulation `r = replicate(10^4,{x = 1:5;  y = x+rnorm(5);  m = lm(y~x); m$residuals[c(1,3)]});plot(t(r)); var(r[1,]); var(r[2,]);`

Comment: By $\hat{\epsilon}$ you are referring to the residuals or to estimates of the error terms?

Comment: $$\hat{\epsilon}$ is the estimate of the error terms

Comment: beta1_hat, beta2_hat are the distributions of the parameter estimates (I think they are asymptotically normal)

Comment: I am feeling lost and overwhelmed by the different notations and distributions ... can you please help me sort this out ? what are the correct theoretical/empirical distributions? and how can simulating new data points assist in confirming if the assumptions are met or not? Thank you so much....

Comment: Do you mean *simulating* new data points or *measuring* new data points?

Comment: I may post an answer about the distribution of $\hat{\beta}_1$ and $\hat{\beta}_2$, but I do not understand what you mean by $\hat{\epsilon}$.

Comment: I thought that epsilon hat is the observed residual? in practice, these observed residuals are supposed to have a Normal Distribution... this means that the model fits well?

Comment: I am just confused... is it really possible to simulate completely new pairs of points ... and then use them to check if the model and data satisfy the required assumptions?

Comment: I always hear that simulation is important in statistics and simulation can be used to see if statistical assumptions are being met... but it is unclear to me how and why?

Comment: The hat symbol $\hat{}$ is used for *estimates*. The errors $\epsilon$ are normally not estimated (instead the parameters of the error distribution, like variance, are estimated).

Comment: *"is it really possible to simulate completely new pairs of points"* I don't understand what you mean by simulation in this comment and in the question.

Comment: my apologies... I think I have overcomplicated everything. Let me restart. Suppose I fit a simple linear regression model to some data. How can simulation help me determine if the necessary statistical assumptions are being met? Thank you so much,,,

Comment: hi sextus ... does my latest comment make sense?

Comment: There is no point simulating based on the statistical assumptions to see whether the simulated output satisfies these assumptions, if that is what you are asking.